# What does deletion of post cost?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-posts

Do I lose reputation on deleting my post with score -3? I just lost my reputation by 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a post gets deleted, you lose all the reputation you gained/lost on it*.

So if you have an answer with:

- 2 upvotes
- 5 downvotes

for a total of -3. You earned `2*10 - 5*2 = 10` for that post. Deleting it will make you lose that 10 rep.

*Some exceptions apply:

- If your post is ["historic"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), you won't lose the rep.
- IIRC, if there are any flags on the post, you may not always regain any rep you lost on it. (I'm unsure of the exact situations...)