# On deleting a question what happens to the reputations gained on its answers

Tags: discussion, support, answers, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does deletion of post cost?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127345/what-does-deletion-of-post-cost)

> A user deletes his answer. At that point what will happen to the
>   reputation earned by the users who posted the various answers for that
>   question?.

case 1: If the reputation still remains and question is deleted, there will be no record for the reputation earned by the user?

case 2: If the reputations earned for the answers also get reduced from various user accounts, is it fare as those votes were given by the other users on stack overflow who rated the answer as good?

Comment: Reputations earned for the answers get reduced from the account

Comment: @Mayankswami Thats wat i also thought. But i tried deleting his post itself. But itsays "This post has upvoted answers and cannot be deleted" and i can only flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reputation gained will go into the great null bucket in the sky. That is, it will disappear - you will see that in the profile reputation page.

Is it fair? If the question was deleted, it was probably a bad question and should have been deleted (and the answers shouldn't have been given in the first place).

If a question has answers with upvotes, the OP can't delete it, so this doesn't come into play.

Comment: I believe any votes on posts that get deleted goes to [the community user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=summary) this explains how it has 80,894 "Votes Cast"